# Accessing OneDrive files on a ntfs partition from Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mount, windows-8, ntfs

I have dual boot on my computer, Win 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04. It works great. There is one thing that puzzles me though. I mounted NTFS partition so I can see it in "Files" app and work with it normaly and I even pointed ubuntu dropbox there, to save some space (both windows and ubuntu dropbox installations are pointing to the same folder on NTFS disk).

The thing is, when I try to access OneDrive folder, instead of files I get something wierd.

This is how dropbox files look like:

[image]

This is how onedrive folder looks like in ubuntu

[image]

When I right click on one of the files in OneDrive folder it says its type is "Link to symbolic link (inode/symlink)"

all my other files on NTFS partition seem to look OK (and i can work with them - i.e. open - normaly from "Files" app)

What am I missing here? How can I access OneDrive files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the craziest solution. Booted back to windows and started inspecting the files. Accidentally I had network traffic monitor opened up and each time I opened a file there was some incoming traffic happening.

So yes, you've guessed it. These inode/symlinks were not links to a file in some other location, but were actual links to Onedrive's cloud. OneDrive acted as sort of overlay and it mimicked files as if they were there, so I was able to open those files in Windows, but not in Ubuntu.

What you have to do in order to access them from other OS than Windows is: open each and every file so it is downloaded on demand. I hope MS will update OneDrive so it does that in background, because this is just silly =)